# Custom Admin Grid page showing blank page in Magento1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, grid-layout

Tying to create a custom grid with the custom module but getting a blank page on grid page like below image.
[image]

Here is my module name : **Ds_Questions**

> app/code/local/Ds/Questions/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ds_Questions>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Ds_Questions>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <questions>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ds_Questions</module>
                    <frontName>questions</frontName>
                </args>
            </questions>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <questions>
                    <file>questions.xml</file>
                </questions>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <questions before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ds_Questions_Adminhtml</questions>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
    <adminhtml>   
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <questions>
                    <file>questions.xml</file>
                </questions>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Ds_Questions>
                        <title>Questions Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <items module="questions">
                                <title>Manage Question</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                <action>adminhtml/questions</action>
                            </items>
                        </children>
                    </Ds_Questions>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl> 
    <global>
        <models>
            <questions>
                <class>Ds_Questions_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>questions_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </questions>
            <questions_mysql4>
                <class>Ds_Questions_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <questions>
                        <table>questions</table>
                    </questions>
                </entities>
            </questions_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <questions_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ds_Questions</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </questions_setup>
            <questions_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </questions_write>
            <questions_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </questions_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <questions>
                <class>Ds_Questions_Block</class>
            </questions>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <questions>
                <class>Ds_Questions_Helper</class>
            </questions>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Ds/Questions/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <questions module="questions">
            <title>Questions</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <items module="questions">
                    <title>Manage Question</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/questions</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </questions>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <questions module="questions">
                        <title>questions</title>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <items module="questions">
                                <title>Manage Question</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                <action>adminhtml/questions</action>
                            </items>
                        </children>
                    </questions>
                </children>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <questions translate="title" module="questions">
                                        <title>questions</title>
                                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                    </questions>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                 </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/questions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.1">
    <adminhtml_questions_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="questions/adminhtml_questions" name="questions" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_questions_index>
</layout>
```

> app/code/local/Ds/Questions/Block/Adminhtml/Questions.php

```
<?php
class Ds_Questions_Block_Adminhtml_Questions extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    die("hiiii");
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_questions';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'questions';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('questions')->__('Questions List');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('questions')->__('Add Question');
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

?>
```

> app/code/local/Ds/Questions/Block/Adminhtml/Questions/Grid.php

```
<?php

class Ds_Questions_Block_Adminhtml_Questions_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setId('questionsGrid');
      $this->setDefaultSort('question_id');
      $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
      $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
  }

  protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
      $collection = Mage::getModel('questions/questions')->getCollection();
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }

  protected function _prepareColumns()
  {
      $this->addColumn('question_id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('questions')->__('ID'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width'     => '50px',
          'index'     => 'question_id',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('question', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Question'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'question',
      ));


      $this->addColumn('link', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Link'),
      'width'     => '150px',
      'index'     => 'link',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('desc', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Description'),
            'width'     => '150px',
            'index'     => 'desc',
      ));


      $this->addColumn('status', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Status'),
          'align'     => 'left',
          'width'     => '80px',
          'index'     => 'status',
          'type'      => 'options',
          'options'   => array(
              1 => 'Enabled',
              2 => 'Disabled',
          ),
      ));

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('questions')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

        //$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('questions')->__('CSV'));
        //$this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('questions')->__('XML'));

      return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('question_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('questions');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Delete'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
             'confirm'  => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('questions/status')->getOptionArray();

        array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('questions')->__('Change status'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
             'additional' => array(
                    'visibility' => array(
                         'name' => 'status',
                         'type' => 'select',
                         'class' => 'required-entry',
                         'label' => Mage::helper('questions')->__('Status'),
                         'values' => $statuses
                     )
             )
        ));
        return $this;
    }

  public function getRowUrl($row)
  {
      return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
  }

}
```

> app/code/local/Ds/Questions/Block/Adminhtml/Questions/Edit.php

```
<?php

class Ds_Questions_Block_Adminhtml_Questions_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'questions';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_questions';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('questions')->__('Save Question'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('questions')->__('Delete Question'));

        $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
            'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class'     => 'save',
        ), -100);

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('questions_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'questions_content');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'questions_content');
                }
            }

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('questions_data') && Mage::registry('questions_data')->getId() ) {
            return Mage::helper('questions')->__("Edit Question '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('questions_data')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('questions')->__('Add Question');
        }
    }
}
```

and there are other files as well like **Form.php** and **Tabs.php** under folder **app/code/local/Ds/Questions/Block/Adminhtml/Questions/Edit/**

Although all file permission are set.

I can't figure out why admin layout file is not working.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, do you have any error in logs ? (exception.log or server's php log ?)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have following files:
**app/etc/modules/Ds_Question.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ds_Questions>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ds_Questions>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ds/Questions/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

class Ds_Questions_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{}
```

**app/code/local/Ds/Questions/controllers/Adminhtml/QuestionsController.php**

```
<?php

class Ds_Questions_Adminhtml_QuestionsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```